# Getting status of olMailItem visibility (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm doing some scripting in PowerShell involving sending some mail automatically. I'm aware that the olMailItem object (on 2003 at least) has a couple of methods, Display() and Close() but is it possible to get the current visibility status?

If I run the following:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail1 = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail1.To = $_.UserID
$Mail1.SentOnBehalfOfName = "me@mydomain.com"
$Mail1.Subject = $Subject1
$Mail1.Body = $BodyText1
$Mail1.Display()

$a = $Mail1

$Mail1.Close()

$b = $Mail1
```

I can't see any difference between $a and $b
What I was hoping for was a $Mail.IsVisible bool property or something.
Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the Application.Inspectors collection and compare each Inspector.CurrentItem.EntryId with MailItem.EntryId property of the item in question. If it is you who create the item and do not save it first, how can be opened in one of the Inspectors? You are the only one who can show it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you.
My point was that when you invoke the Close() method, the mailItem is not destroyed, it remains there in seemingly the same state (including the same EntryID), the only difference is that it's not visible. I can't find any variable that changes between the Close() state and the Display() state. Even the window position doesn't change as it does when the window is minimised.
I'm stumped.

Comment: There is no such property. Again, the only way to check the visibility state is to look at the items that *are* being displayed (Application.Inspectors) and check if your item is one of them.

Comment: Aah, that makes sense now.
The following will return True if the item is visible:
    ($outlook.Inspectors|Select CurrentItem|%{$_.CurrentItem.EntryID -match $Mail1.EntryID}) -contains $True